# php call function when connected to file

Tags: php

I've try to call a function in php. I've connected with an ajax call to the file (works fine). My question in now how can I call the function?

```
if (isset($_POST['callFunc1']) && !empty($_POST['callFunc1'])) {
    echo 'get the echo';
    function generateWigaNews()
    {
        echo 'don't get the echo';
    }
}
```

Comment: where you want to call function ? From ajax or php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['callFunc1']) && !empty($_POST['callFunc1'])) {
    echo 'get the echo';
    function generateWigaNews()
    {
        echo "don't get the echo";
    }
    generateWigaNews() //call function
}
```

Comment: What I tried is to call the function before the implementation. Thanks for the information. +1